# Triggering an intent in my dialogflow webhook does not allow use of it's followup intents

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

From my `Deals List - yes` intent, if I direct the user to another intent called `Product Details` by evoking its action with `conv.followup()`. It will send the user there with it's expected parameters.

```
conv.followup('product_detail_intent_event', {
    product: productName
});
```

So far, so good, however, the `Product Detail` intent has a yes followup intent of its own that is defined on dialogflow and handled in our webhook. This follow up intent triggers as expected under normal circumstances, but not when we have entered the product detail intent via the `conv.followup()` method.

If the user says yes, it repeats the `Product Detail` intent. If they say yes again, it will then work as expected.

My suspicion was that dialogflow had not been updated about the changed intent and therefore did not know about the followup, but logging `conv.intent` returns the intent `Product Detail` which is the correct and expected intent.

Do I need to do something extra to inform dialogflow that the user is now in the `Product Detail` intent and that a `yes` followup intent is available from this point?

**EDIT**: Just so it is clear, the intent I am coming from `Deals List - yes` is a yes followup itself. Not sure if this is perhaps what may be confusing dialogflow

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved, our yes followup intent for Deals List had incorrect contexts from when we renamed it in Dialogflow. Rebuilding the parent and it's followups in Dialogflow resolved the issue